# How to test an angular $scope function?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, testing

I'm trying make a test for my angular control. How do I test a variable that is in a function?

example:

```
$scope.onFileSelect = function($files) {
$scope.selectedFiles = [];
$scope.progress = [];

if ($scope.upload && $scope.upload.length > 0) {
  for (var i = 0; i < $scope.upload.length; i++) {
    if ($scope.upload[i] !== null) {
      $scope.upload[i].abort();
    }
  }
}
$scope.upload = [];
$scope.uploadResult = [];
$scope.selectedFiles = $files;
$scope.dataUrls = [];



    if ($scope.selectedFiles.length==1) {
      for ( var i = 0; i < $files.length; i++) {
        var $file = $files[i];
        if (window.FileReader && $file.type.indexOf('image') > -1) {
          var fileReader = new FileReader();
          fileReader.readAsDataURL($files[i]);
          var loadFile = function(fileReader, index) {
            fileReader.onload = function(e) {
              $timeout(function() {
                $scope.dataUrls[index] = e.target.result;
              });
            };
          }(fileReader, i);
        }
        $scope.progress[i] = -1;
        if ($scope.uploadRightAway) {
          $scope.start(i);
        }
      }

    }
    else{
      $scope.selectedFiles = null;
      $scope.clientmsg={};
      $scope.errormessageheader="";
      $scope.uploadErrors="";
      $scope.UploadSuccess="";
      auxArray = [""];
      $scope.uploadErrors =auxArray;
      $scope.errormessageheader="Only_submit_one_file";
    }
  };
```

and my test...

```
describe('Unit: routeAssignUpload_Ctrl', function () {

beforeEach(angular.mock.module('primaryDistributionApp'));

var ctrl, scope;
// inject the $controller and $rootScope services
// in the beforeEach block
beforeEach(inject(function($controller, $rootScope) {
// Create a new scope that's a child of the $rootScope
scope = $rootScope.$new();
// Create the controller
ctrl = $controller('routeAssignUpload_Ctrl', {
  $scope: scope
});
}));



it('probando funcion onFileSelect',function(){
expect(scope.onFileSelect).toBeDefined();
var onFileSelect1 = new scope.onFileSelect;
spyOn(onFileSelect1).andCallThrough();
expect(scope.upload).toBeDefined();
});


})
```

the result is "TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object" (evaluating '$scope.selectedFile
s.length')
I don't understand why, can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things to consider.

1. Why are you using the `new` keyword when trying to call `scope.onFileSelect`? This is just a scope method, you don't need to (and probably don't want to) use it as a constructor method.
2. You aren't passing any variable into `scope.onFileSelect`. This means the `$files` variable is `undefined`. You then assign it via `$scope.selectedFiles = $files;` and test its length (`if ($scope.selectedFiles.length==1) { ... }`). As the error indicates, `undefined` has no `length` property.

I also don't see any reason you need to spy on `onFileSelect` -- you are testing its behavior, and you are calling it directly; using `spyOn(..).andCallThrough` is most useful when you want to test that some other function calls into this for your, without interrupting its behavior. Your test could probably be better written as follows (flesh out to test more interesting behavior):

```
it('probando funcion onFileSelect',function(){
    var files = ['fileA', 'fileB'];
    expect(scope.onFileSelect).toBeDefined();
    scope.onFileSelect(files);
    expect(scope.selectedFiles).toBe(files);
    expect(scope.upload).toBeDefined(); // or whatever
});
```

The question you should be asking yourself is what behavior you are really trying to test. Currently, this isn't a very interesting test -- you know that `upload` is defined, but you don't know anything interesting about it yet.

Comment: Thanks, really i'm noob in JS and noobin angular and testing, this is my firts spec and i dont know hows to make a good unit test, i dont know what behavior test, if you can guide me , I would appreciate. I run your answer and the result is  "Expected null to be [ 'fileA', 'fileB' ]" ,  this meannig that scope.selectedFiles may be null? Why?

Comment: That's because I didn't read your original code carefully enough. It is caused by the following: `if ($scope.selectedFiles.length==1) { ... } else{ $scope.selectedFiles = null; ... }` So, it's null because my example used an array with length 2 instead of length 1. I can see that you add an error message if more than one file is submitted, which makes me wonder why you expect an array for $files instead of a single string argument `filename` or similar. The code you have will effectively limit you to 1, as you seem to expect, but doesn't seem like the cleanest route.